# logged on user name with VB code not picking up all names

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro that looks to a range on a sheet (named "Sheet2") and if this matches to the logged on user name with VB code it runs the second half. For some users this works and for others it does not.

I cannot figure out what the reason is that some users cannot run it?

I have this at the start of my function as some users are windows 7 and some are windows 10 (this is not the divide on who can run it or not)

```
#If Win64 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _
(ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#Else
Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _
(ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Actual Code when user runs:

```
Dim ret As Long, UserName As String

ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 25)
UserName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)

Myrow = 0
blankrow = 0
Do Until Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Offset(Myrow, 0) = ""
If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Offset(Myrow, 0) = UserName Then GoTo 1

Myrow = Myrow + 1

Loop

MsgBox "You are not authorised to finalise the end of day, only specified people can complete", vbCritical, "BBH Oversight"
Exit Sub

1
```

Can anyone see a fault in the code that is causing the discrepancy?

[This is the sheet its looks up (Sheet2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOS3A.png)

Comment: First you don't have to use GoTo statement you can exit do loop with Exit Do.When you say it doesn't work for some users what exactly happens ?

Comment: The user sees the following message:  "You are not authorised to finalise the end of day, only specified people can complete". when it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens for other users , If you are seeing the msgbox for other users it means both values are not matching.Could you try adding one line in msgbox statement '& UserName' without single quotes and see what it shows.

Comment: It just picked up the word UserName. I may have added it wrong. I did find out that the spreadsheet was split into 3, with the same macro in each. Could it be looking back at an old version that the new users are not listed on?

Comment: Add the line in all the sheets code Debug.Print UserName and see what it returns in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting both username and comparison string to upper case.

```
Dim ret As Long, UserName As String

ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 25)
UserName = UCase(Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1))

Myrow = 0
blankrow = 0
Do Until Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Offset(Myrow, 0) = ""
If UCase(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Offset(Myrow, 0)) = UserName Then GoTo 1

Myrow = Myrow + 1

Loop

MsgBox "You are not authorised to finalise the end of day, only specified people can complete", vbCritical, "BBH Oversight"
Exit Sub

1
```